# Symfony 2.1 and MopaBootstrapBundle (Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!)

Tags: twig, symfony-2.1

I installed MopaBootstrapBlundle via Composer in symfony 2.1.5-DEV. After ativate the bundle in Appkernel.php I get a fatal error.

Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /home/sandy/desarrollo/www/bengala/frontbengala.dev/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Token.php on line 78

I used this bundle in other project with sf 2.0.x without problems.

How to resolve error?

Comment: As a first step you could increase your max nesting level, 200 usually does the trick (this is a problem many meet when using Sf2).

Comment: In your php.ini. A google search will give you the exact key to modify.

Comment: Thanks. I set xdebug.max_nesting_level=200 in xdebug.ini. And error is gone, but I'm not sure how work on production servers because I can't change this conf here.

Comment: It won't be a problem, as production servers don't have xdebug installed.